# Can advice (a noun) be used as advices (a verb)?

Tags: american-english, british-english, verb-forms

As per my opinion (as we all know this) advice is a noun and it does not have any plural form and it also can not be used as a verb (not sure about a verb). As per my daily routine I was reading the news on Yahoo and found out an error, so I think, I should clear my doubt here (as I always do).

**On Yahoo:**

> Legend has it that site was blessed by Lord Krishna. On this
>   knowledge, a holy man **advices** King Jaiswal to build his fort here,
>   where it will remain invisible to his enemies. Named for its golden
>   hue, it is known as Jaisalmer's Sonar Quila or Golden Fort.

**It should be:**

> advices = advises.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're right; they're wrong.  I actually think this may have been written by a non-native speaker. There's at least one other error. In the first sentence; there should be a "the" before site. The phrase "On this knowledge" is also odd - if it's not outright wrong it's not idiomatic, at least to my eye.

Comment: @Nigel That's the answer - Post it!

Comment: @NigelHarper Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: Using _advices_ as a verb is either wrong grammar, or a typo.

Answer (score 7):

You're right; they're wrong. "Advices" should be "advises".

I think this piece may actually have been written by a non-native speaker, for a couple of reasons.

Firstly there's another clear error.

> Legend has it that site was blessed by Lord Krishna.

is wrong.  It should probably be

> Legend has it that **the** site was blessed by Lord Krishna.

Missing out an article is a classic non-native speaker error which we often see here on ELL.

> Legend has it that **that** site was blessed by Lord Krishna.

would also be grammatically correct and could make sense depending on what has gone before (thanks to BobRodes for suggesting this alternative in the comments).

Secondly the phrase "On this knowledge" at the start of the second sentence is odd.  If it's not outright wrong it's certainly not idiomatic, at least to my eye.

Comment: This is a clear error as you say, but I'd like to point out something.  Another correction could be "Legend has it that that site was blessed by Lord Krishna."  In conversation, "that that" is fairly often replaced by "that" (when both are spoken the first one is usually pretty attenuated anyway, sort of a quick "tht THAT"), so a (tenuous) case could be made that the statement as written is not 100% incorrect.

Comment: Good point; "that that" might well work depending on what had gone before. As is so often said here context is everything.